# How to use Java API to close NotesUIDocument without a pop-up in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm trying to close NotesUIDocument but there is always a pop-up dialog to ask whether to save or send the document. I know how the trick in LotusScript, which is modify 'SaveOptions' to '0', but have no idea how to access 'SaveOptions' by Java. I also think of a workaround that save the ui document, close it and delete the corresponding document in database. But surprisingly the dialog shows again even though the document has been saved.

Here is part of my codes:

```
NotesUIWorkspace ws = new NotesUIWorkspace();
NotesUIElement element = ws.getCurrentElement();
NotesUIDocument doc = (NotesUIDocument) element;
doc.save();
doc.close();
```

Is there anyone that knows how to make it work in Java? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the trick in Java. Here is the codes:

```
// close ui document without saving
NotesBEDocument docbe = doc.getBEDocument();
docbe.setItemValue("SaveOptions", "0");
docbe.setItemValue("MailOptions", "0");
doc.close();
docbe.removeItem("SaveOptions");
docbe.removeItem("MailOptions");
```

Both SaveOptions and MailOptions need to be modified in order to hide the dialog.